# Middle-click in editor preview pastes in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, google-chrome

When I click the middle mouse button on a link in the preview area of the [editor](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/), in Chrome, this opens the link in a new tab and pastes the clipboard content at the cursor position. The expected behavior would be to open the link in a new tab, only: a middle-click in the preview area should never paste. A middle click not on a link does not paste.

Observed in Chrome 27.0.1453.93 and 28.0.1500.95 under Linux (Debian wheezy, Ubuntu 12.04) and in some prior versions, I've forgotten when this started but it isn't new. Reproduced in incognito mode, not logged in and with no extensions. In my tests, this happens systematically when the editor is in a separate tab (whether I'm editing my own post or suggesting an edit), but not when the editor is inline. Not reproduced in Firefox.

Comment: What Linux (distro/version)? Latest Chrome on Windoze does not reproduce.

Comment: @Oded Windows doesn't understand the middle mouse button, so I don't expect this to be reproducible on Windows. Debian wheezy, when I posted this. Hmmm, I can't reproduce it now on Ubuntu 12.04. I think I did have the same problem with Ubuntu 10.04 but I don't have one around with a GUI any more.

Comment: I have Mint and Fedora VMs, so will try to repro there.

Comment: Can you clarify on where the clipboard contents gets pasted?

Comment: @Oded At the location of the cursor (not the location of the click), which doesn't change.

Comment: Fedora, Chrome 28.0.1500.95, no repro.

Comment: @Oded Ah, reproduced now on Ubuntu 12.04 with Chrome 28.0.1500.95. Steps: copy the URL of this question. Open an incognito window and paste the URL. Click on “improve this question”. Middle-click on the “edtior” link, and in addition to opening the URL in a new tab, the URL of the question is pasted at the beginning of the question. On the other hand, if I edit inline, I can't reproduce the bug. In fact, it seems that I can only reproduce when editing in a separate window (i.e. <1k rep, whether editing my own post or suggesting an edit), and not when the editor is inline.

Comment: Yes, looks like this only happens in the non-inline version of the editor. Reproduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added a check for middle clicking on the preview.

Code was always refocusing into the textarea - for middle clicking that will no longer happen.

With you in the next build.